# How do I pass arguments to a bash script using a pipe?

Tags: bash, unix, stdin, pipeline

I want to pass an argument to a read command within this script via a pipe or some other method.

My command within the script is

```
read -p "Change Parameters?
while [ $REPLY != "n" ]
do
        if  [ $REPLY == "a" ]
        then
..
..
        if [ $REPLY =="j" ]
..
done
```

The read command appears on line 48 of my script if thats of any use

I've tried

```
./script argument1 argument2 | bash /dev/stdin "n"
```

which results in

```
Change Parameters? /dev/stdin: line 1: Default: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 2: a: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 3: b: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 4: c: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 5: d: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 6: e: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 7: f: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 8: g: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 9: h: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 10: i: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 11: j: command not found
/dev/stdin: line 12: n: command not found
```

And then stops

I just want to pass the letter n to this command and for the script to continue till the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pipe is the wrong way around, to pass `n` to the script you need to write

```
echo "n" | ./script argument1 argument2
```

Another example:

```
echo "abcd" | { read -p "Change Parameters?" b; echo $b; }
```

Output:

```
abcd
```

In the second example the `{ ... }` part is your script, `echo "abcd"` is piped to the script, `read` gets the "abcd" (the prompt `Change parameters?` is not shown), saves it in the variable `$b`, then `$b` is echoed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to follow the echo way (echo something and pipe it to your script) you just need to change your command:

```
./script argument1 argument2 | bash /dev/stdin "n"
```

To

```
./script argument1 argument2 <<<"n"
```

Or

```
./script argument1 argument2 <<<"$var"
```